# How to load dataset in libsvm python

Tags: python, dataset, libsvm

I am wandering how can I load my dataset, in order to read it from libsvm python implementation. My data is a 250X500 matrix and the first column is dataset labels. I am using the following code in order to read the data:

```
with open("dataset3.txt") as textFile:
lines = [line.split() for line in textFile]

Matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(len(lines[0]))] for x in xrange(len(lines))] 

for y in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x in range(0, len(lines[0])):
        Matrix[y][x] = lines[y][x]
```

With the code above I read my data into a 2d array of int. How can I use this array in order to perform svm train and evaluation??

```
param = svm_parameter('-t 0 -c 4 -b 1')
m = svm_train(Matrix, param)
```

Text file:

```
1   0   9   0   0   0   0   5   2   5   15   2   3   50   0   4   6   27   0   16   34   0   11   30   12   23   41   1   0   2   0   10   67   34 ...
-1   0   10   0   0   0   0   1   0   2   5   1   8   14   0   12   11   4   2   4   22   0   6   40   8   20   47   2   1   0   0   2   1   21   0   1   11   1  ...
...

Matrix = []
with open('dataset3.txt') as f:
row = []
for line in f:
    data = line.split()
    target = float(data[0]) # target value
    str1 = str(target) 
    for i,j in enumerate(data):
        if i==0:
            continue
        else:   
            str1 = str1 + " " + str(i) +":"+ str(j) +" " 
row.append(str1)
```

Comment: please provide `dataset3.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
with open('dataset3.txt') as f:
    Matrix = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]
```

- `for line in f` reads each line.
- `line.split()` splits into each `value`
- `map(float, line.split())` converts `value` to `float`

**Updated**

OP commented different input format.

```
Matrix = []
with open('dataset3.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        target = float(data[0]) # target value
        row = []

        for i, (idx, value) in enumerate([item.split(':') for item in data[1:]]):
            n = int(idx) - (i + 1) # num missing
            for _ in range(n):
                row.append(0) # for missing
            row.append(float(value))
        Matrix.append(row)
```

Comment: No it doesnt work, I found that the data morphology must be like that: +1 1:0.708333 2:1 3:1 4:-0.320755 5:-0.105023 6:-1 7:1 8:-0.419847 9:-1 10:-0.225806 12:1 13:-1

Comment: The text file you provide was `1   0   9   0   0   0   0   5   2   5   15   2 ` ...

Comment: Yes exactly a array of 251x461 values like the ones provided.

Comment: I am getting :    for i, (idx, value) in enumerate([item.split(':') for item in data[1:]]):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack